# Intermittent Connection Issues on High Traffic Servers

Tags: networking, nginx, haproxy

Some brief background: We've been getting reports of very intermittent connection issues from our users. Several times per day, users will have to reload the page they're on due to a connection failure or an SSL handshake issue (which I think is due to the connection issues). It happens so fast that I have been unable to gather any data during these incidents. It tends to go away on its own only to come back again later, typically during peak hours of traffic.

A little bit about our setup: We have three virtual IPs in round robin DNS, managed by keepalived for our pool of app servers. nginx is accepting SSL connections, which go upstream to haproxy to get distributed to other app servers. Since these problems started, I have updated all software on the servers (including going from CentOS5 to CentOS6), which has not helped. I have posted here already about our nginx configuration, which appears to be fine. It is largely based on Mozilla's nginx config generator for SSL best practices.

I have been advised to pay attention to TCP stat counters. I'm not quite sure how to interpret these, however. This is the output I have from `netstat -s` on an app server I restarted yesterday (so presumably the counters were at 0 yesterday):

```
Ip:
    1021579809 total packets received
    4875 forwarded
    0 incoming packets discarded
    1021562810 incoming packets delivered
    1033056732 requests sent out
    1 outgoing packets dropped
    76648 dropped because of missing route
    2 fragments dropped after timeout
    7072 reassemblies required
    2020 packets reassembled ok
    2 packet reassembles failed
    1514 fragments received ok
    6056 fragments created
Icmp:
    20522423 ICMP messages received
    533 input ICMP message failed.
    ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 20503410
        timeout in transit: 2013
        wrong parameters: 2
        source quenches: 10
        redirects: 8264
        echo requests: 8256
        echo replies: 2
    20497056 ICMP messages sent
    0 ICMP messages failed
    ICMP output histogram:
        destination unreachable: 20488798
        time exceeded: 1
        echo request: 1
        echo replies: 8256
IcmpMsg:
        InType0: 2
        InType3: 20503410
        InType4: 10
        InType5: 8264
        InType8: 8256
        InType11: 2013
        InType12: 2
        OutType0: 8256
        OutType3: 20488798
        OutType8: 1
        OutType11: 1
Tcp:
    46263582 active connections openings
    30767670 passive connection openings
    104167 failed connection attempts
    2769710 connection resets received
    104167 failed connection attempts
    2769710 connection resets received
    6428 connections established
    979651572 segments received
    989059642 segments send out
    2386512 segments retransmited
    1454 bad segments received.
    4277435 resets sent
Udp:
    32926 packets received
    21204463 packets to unknown port received.
    0 packet receive errors
    21033739 packets sent
UdpLite:
TcpExt:
    624791 invalid SYN cookies received
    96083 resets received for embryonic SYN_RECV sockets
    367 packets pruned from receive queue because of socket buffer overrun
    54 ICMP packets dropped because they were out-of-window
    21204114 TCP sockets finished time wait in fast timer
    57674 packets rejects in established connections because of timestamp
    38714053 delayed acks sent
    12521 delayed acks further delayed because of locked socket
    Quick ack mode was activated 6563499 times
    62 times the listen queue of a socket overflowed
    62 SYNs to LISTEN sockets ignored
    74285057 packets directly queued to recvmsg prequeue.
    554544554 packets directly received from backlog
    34503032789 packets directly received from prequeue
    336811743 packets header predicted
    75957393 packets header predicted and directly queued to user
    210355614 acknowledgments not containing data received
    318977957 predicted acknowledgments
    1663 times recovered from packet loss due to fast retransmit
    181338 times recovered from packet loss due to SACK data
    898 bad SACKs received
    Detected reordering 1847 times using FACK
    Detected reordering 3512 times using SACK
    Detected reordering 40 times using reno fast retransmit
    Detected reordering 16201 times using time stamp
    46565 congestion windows fully recovered
    49940 congestion windows partially recovered using Hoe heuristic
    TCPDSACKUndo: 196240
    204108 congestion windows recovered after partial ack
    63640 TCP data loss events
    TCPLostRetransmit: 4150
    747 timeouts after reno fast retransmit
    40359 timeouts after SACK recovery
    24399 timeouts in loss state
    286482 fast retransmits
    71966 forward retransmits
    317608 retransmits in slow start
    802284 other TCP timeouts
    TCPRenoRecoveryFail: 324
    14820 sack retransmits failed
    22966 packets collapsed in receive queue due to low socket buffer
    6453991 DSACKs sent for old packets
    1781 DSACKs sent for out of order packets
    649408 DSACKs received
    3047 DSACKs for out of order packets received
    1733842 connections reset due to unexpected data
    100890 connections reset due to early user close
    98451 connections aborted due to timeout
    TCPSACKDiscard: 446
    TCPDSACKIgnoredOld: 4660
    TCPDSACKIgnoredNoUndo: 161136
    TCPSpuriousRTOs: 15474
    TCPSackShifted: 296768
    TCPSackMerged: 495277
    TCPSackShiftFallback: 944017
    TCPChallengeACK: 82577
    TCPSYNChallenge: 287
    TCPFromZeroWindowAdv: 5279
    TCPToZeroWindowAdv: 5279
    TCPWantZeroWindowAdv: 35932
IpExt:
    InMcastPkts: 151429
    OutMcastPkts: 151501
    InOctets: 947588463980
    OutOctets: 692622505019
    InMcastOctets: 6360064
    OutMcastOctets: 6060040
```

Besides `netstat -s`, are there any other tools I can use to get a better understanding of what is going on here?

Some changes I have made recently (after these problems began). Other params are set to default as I haven't changed them.

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog: 4096
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout: 30
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range: 15000 65000
/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: 500000
```

Updated with relevant graphs from Cacti:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have some warnings in dmesg ? What's your conntrack timeouts ? That can come from many things ...

Comment: I assume you mean  /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established? It is currently set to 432000 on all servers. And no warnings in dmesg.

Comment: Do you have the cacti graph with the amount of socket in each TCP state for the same period of time ? And the CPU usage on the LVS box ? [Aggregate graphs](http://docs.cacti.net/plugin:aggregate) would allow to get a better picture too.

Comment: I do not. Is it safe to poll netstat for this info every few minutes? I have heard that there is a performance overhead associated with it for large production traffic.

Comment: Depends what's your definition of large. On a 50 VMs platform for instance I did not see performance impact. And that's a must to have. But as you will rely on open source scripts then there's always a risk for a script to take some time because something was badly designed/tested.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried using snmpnetstat with cacti and began getting snmp timeouts. This was even with a 300s step set with a 600s heartbeat. The server is currently handling about 10k connections, and running netstat on the machine takes a long time to finish.

Comment: I personally use [conntrack status](http://forums.cacti.net/about36629.html).

Comment: @XavierLucas Thank you very much for that link. I got conntrack-tools installed and Cacti graphing some output from that script. Will report back soon.

Comment: @XavierLucas I updated the post to include the output so far.

Comment: ifconfig , and  4875 forwarded (have you got ip routing enabled) , also 76648 dropped because of missing route (do you have routing instability)